# Dygraph - hide axis labels when not showing data

Tags: dygraphs

I do not know how to hide an axis' labels from the graph when the visibility of all data in the series that is to show with that axis is hidden. The axes show without any problem, but when the two series (below in my code) that a particular axis are hidden the axis remains visible and the labels change from 0 to 1 in 1/10 increments. I will be grateful for any suggestions. Below is the code I am using:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>The lines should maintain their colors as their visibility is toggled.</p>
<div id="blah"></div>
<p><b>Display: </b>
<input type=checkbox id=0 onClick="change(this)" checked>
<label for="0"> UX</label>
<input type=checkbox id=1 onClick="change(this)"><!-- got rid of checked -->
<label for="1"> EX</label>
<input type=checkbox id=2 onClick="change(this)" checked>
<label for="2"> JX</label>
<input type=checkbox id=3 onClick="change(this)" checked>
<label for="2"> EJ</label>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  chart = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("blah"),
                    "date,UX,EX,JX,EJ\n" +
                    "10,3.0,4.15,133.1,140.1\n" +
        "11,3.3,4.18,100.9,135.3\n" +
                    "12,3.25,4.20,115.9,145.5\n" + 
        "13,3.35,4.16,98.9,106.8\n", 
                      {
        width: 640,
        height: 480,
        labelsSeparateLines: false,
        hideOverlayOnMouseOut: true,
        axisLabelFontSize: 9,
        colors: ['#284785', '#EE1111', '#8AE234', '#00ffff'],   
  series : {
 'UX' : {
  axis : 'y1',
  },
'EX' : {
  axis : 'y1',
  },
  'EJ' : {
  axis : 'y2',
  },
  'JX' : {
  axis : 'y2',
  }
  },
  visibility: [true, false, true, true],
showRangeSelector: true,
rangeSelectorHeight: 30,
labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
    title: 'Currency Pair Correlation',
    ylabel: 'Price',
connectSeparatedPoints: true,
strokeWidth: 3,
strokeBorderWidth: 1,
strokeBorderColor: '#000',
drawPoints : true,
    pointSize : 3,
    highlightCircleSize: 10,
drawPointCallback : Dygraph.Circles.HEXAGON,
    drawHighlightPointCallback : Dygraph.Circles.HEXAGON,
   });
  function change(el) {
    chart.setVisibility(el.id, el.checked);
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it via the dygraphs API, but here is one way to do it. In your change event handler check which series are hidden and determine which axes can therefore be hidden. Then find all text with the class dygraph-axis-label-y and iterate through them. <del>If their parent DIV is aligned right it is a Y1 label, if aligned left it is a Y2 label.</del>

**UPDATE:** danvk pointed out in the comments that y2 labels have the class `dygraph-axis-label-y2`, so I am updating my answer to use this fact.

```
function change(el) {
  chart.setVisibility(el.id, el.checked);
  var y1vis = ($("#0:checked").length + $("#1:checked").length) > 0;
  var y2vis = ($("#2:checked").length + $("#3:checked").length) > 0;      
  if (y1vis){
      $(".dygraph-axis-label-y:not(.dygraph-axis-label-y2)").show();
  } else {
      $(".dygraph-axis-label-y:not(.dygraph-axis-label-y2)").hide();
  }
  if (y2vis){
      $(".dygraph-axis-label-y2").show();
  } else {
      $(".dygraph-axis-label-y2").hide();
  }          
}
```

<del>function change(el) {
        chart.setVisibility(el.id, el.checked);
          var y1vis = ($("#0:checked").length + $("#1:checked").length) > 0;
          var y2vis = ($("#2:checked").length + $("#3:checked").length) > 0;
          if (y1vis && y2vis){
              $(".dygraph-axis-label-y").show();
          } else {
              $(".dygraph-axis-label-y").each(function(){
                  //var IsY1 = $(this).parent().css("text-align") == "right";
                  // use y2 class instead
                  var IsY1 = !$(this).hasClass("dygraph-axis-label-y2");
                  if (IsY1 && !y1vis){
                       $(this).hide();   
                  }
                  if (!IsY1 && !y2vis){
                       $(this).hide();   
                  }
              });
          }
      }</del>

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/U86Fa/2/)**

Comment: The better way to detect a secondary y-axis label is by the presence of the "dygraph-axis-label-y2" class. Primary y-axis labels don't have this.

Comment: @danvk, good catch! I have updated my answer to use the y2 class.